# Dynamic image using JavaScript - adding Widh and Height Attributes

Tags: javascript, image, attributes

My application is MVC 5; I am generating images dynamically based on the width of the div, using the following:

```
 <div id="div1"class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 nopadding">
      <img id="img1" class="img-responsive"/>
 </div>



$("#div1").addClass("col-md-5 col-lg-5").removeClass("col-md-6 col-lg-6");
            var div = document.getElementById("div1");
            var jumpwidth = parseInt(div.offsetWidth);
            var img = new Image();
            img.src =  '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/JumpStart.webp")';
            img.onload = function() {
                var imageElement = document.getElementById("img1");
                imageElement.src = img.src;
                img.setAttribute("width", jumpwidth);
                img.setAttribute("height", parseInt(jumpwidth / 1.5, 10));
                imageElement.maxWidth = jumpwidth;
                imageElement.maxHeight = parseInt(jumpwidth/ 1.5, 10);
                imageElement.alt = "JumpStart";
                imageElement.style.marginLeft = "auto";
                imageElement.style.marginRight = "auto";
            };
```

It works:

```
<img id="img1" class="img-responsive" src="http://localhost:6875/Content/images/JumpStart.webp" alt="JumpStart" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

However it does not add with and heigh! which are important for SEO.

Comment: `imageElement.setAttribute("width", jumpwidth);` and `imageElement.setAttribute("height", parseInt(jumpwidth / 1.5, 10));` instead of `img.setAttribute(...)`?

Answer (score -1):

I added at the end of the script:

```
$("#img1").attr( {
                'width': jumpwidth,
                'height': jumpheight
            });
```

Here is the result

```
<img id="img1" class="img-responsive" width="475" height="316" src="http://localhost:6875/Content/images/JumpStart.webp" alt="JumpStart" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

Comment: horrible workaround, please see comment on your question

Comment: I did my best with the information I had at the time, but I appreciate constructive feedback.